# Can't browse freshly added website in IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, configuration

I have one site (mydevbox.com) that is setup and I browse from IIS to get the standard IIS 7 welcome screen.

I setup a second site (playground.com) so that I won't mess with the settings of the first one. I want to keep normal development setup like production so I don't have to worry about configuration issues like this.

Right now there is no discernable difference between the two configurations. I have playground set to use a different port (8070) than mydevbox (80). I stopped mydevbox and set playground to use the same app pool to check those settings and I still can't get the welcome screen. Instead I get this error:

```
Oops! Google Chrome could not find playground.com:8070
```

Any ideas on what else I could check?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must add the host in the file `host` located in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\

In your case it will be :

```
127.0.0.1      mydevbox.com
127.0.0.1      playground.com
```

PS : It is late answer but this is for the next people having same problem ;-)